# How to to calculate the topic distribution of a document

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, kullback-leibler, information-retrieval

I want to calculate Kullback–Leibler divergence on two documents. It requires probability distribution of each document.

I do not know how to calculate probability for each document. Any simple answer with layman example would be much appreciated.

Let's say we have follow two documents:

```
1 - cross validated answers are good 
2 - simply validated answers are nice
```

(wording of the documents is just bla bla to give you an example)

How do we calculate probabilities for these documents?

Let's say we add one more document:

```
3 - simply cross is not good answer
```

If we add another document then how would it impact probability distribution?

Thanks